# Microsoft public keys only validate id token and not access tokens

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, jwt, bearer-token

I'm trying to validate an access token in my Python app following [this code sample from Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions/blob/master/Function/secureFlaskApp/__init__.py) So in line 99 it's decoding the token using `python-jose` library:

```
payload = jwt.decode(
                    token,
                    rsa_key,
                    algorithms=["RS256"],
                    audience=API_AUDIENCE,
                    issuer="https://sts.windows.net/" + TENANT_ID + "/"
                )
```

But although at line #72 it says:

> """Determines if the Access Token is valid"""

It only works if I pass the id token to it. Every time I pass the access token, I get this error:

```
JWTError: Signature verification failed
```

Seems like the public keys in this urls:

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/discovery/v2.0/keys
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys

work only for ID Tokens.

I really need to validate the access token because its coming from a request and an API with bearer token authorisation. How can I validate the access token instead of id token?

Comment: Can you post the JWT header details? eg by pasting the JWT into the website at jwt.io. Is there a nonce field?

Comment: @GaryArcher Yes, I can see the nonce field in header

Comment: See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001593/azure-jwt-verification-in-go-is-not-working), which explains the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to @Gary I could find the solution. Reading [his blog](https://authguidance.com/azure-ad-troubleshooting/) about the same issue, I found out that:

> If you get a token with a nonce field in the JWT header, then it is
> intended for Microsoft APIs to validate, and will always fail standard
> signature based validation.

To get an access token for custom APIs, I had to define a custom scope in my registered app in Azure portal.

And when I added the new scope in my OIDC configurations in my app, I got a new access token which can be verified by *jwt*.