# how to verify the oauth2 access token provided by MS identity platform

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-app-registration

I have created an oauth2 app using [MS app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) and the plan is to authenticate clients using this app registration.

I am running the following code to authenticate a person using his MS Azure creds.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/microsoft"
)

func main() {
    clientID := "292def6c-3c4c-42ed-9ef2-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    redirectURL := "http://localhost:8000/callback"
    scopes := []string{"User.Read"} // Specify the required scopes

    conf := &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:    clientID,
        RedirectURL: redirectURL,
        Scopes:      scopes,
        Endpoint:    microsoft.AzureADEndpoint("4d16a70b-76a1-4ad7-944a-XXXXXX"), // Replace with your Azure AD tenant ID
    }

    // Generate authorization URL
    authURL := conf.AuthCodeURL("state", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)

    fmt.Printf("Open the following URL in your browser:\n\n%s\n\n", authURL)
    fmt.Println("After authentication, you will be redirected to the specified redirect URL.")

    m := http.NewServeMux()

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8000",
        Handler: m,
    }
    // Start a local HTTP server to listen for the callback
    m.HandleFunc("/callback", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        code := r.URL.Query().Get("code")

        // Exchange authorization code for access token
        token, err := conf.Exchange(context.Background(), code)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Token exchange error:", err)
        }

        // prints the access token to terminal
        fmt.Println("Token:", token.AccessToken)

        // Use the token for further API requests
        // Example: call the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve the user's profile
        client := conf.Client(context.Background(), token)
        resp, err := client.Get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("API request error:", err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        fmt.Println("\nAuthentication successful! You can close the browser.")
        w.Write([]byte("Authentication successful! You can close the browser."))
    })

    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

The above code prints a URL for authentication and starts a server to catch the response and prints the access token in the terminal. Next,I head over to https://login.microsoftonline.com/4d16a70b-76a1-4ad7-944a-13513528982b/discovery/v2.0/keys and match the right public using the access token `kid` key. The idea is that the access token must be signed by one of the public keys from the above URL and the public key can be using the `kid` key from the access token. Now I run the following program which should ideally verify the key.

```golang
func main() {
    // Replace 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' with the actual access token you want to verify
    tokenString := "ENTIRE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    key := "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nTHE_PUBLIC_KEY\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
    // Define the Microsoft AAD public key or certificate URL
    // You may need to update the URL based on your specific AAD configuration
    // microsoftKeysURL := "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys"

    // Parse the token without verifying the signature
    t, err := jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        // Don't forget to validate the alg is what you expect:
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
        }

        return jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM([]byte(key))
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to parse token:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

The above program fails with the following error

```
Failed to parse token:crypto/rsa: verification error
```

There could be two reasons for the error

- I am doing something wrong programmatically.
- I am using wrong public key for the verification, which would be very hard to believe for me because I am matching the public key using kid, i get one key matched out of all those public keys and that should be the right key.

Comment: Does the JWT header contain a nonce field? If so see [this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76001593/azure-jwt-verification-in-go-is-not-working).

Comment: @GaryArcher yes, the header indeed contains the nonce field - going to check out your answer now.